# Handling Back button when keyboard is up

Tags: android, events, methods

In My Application I have an EditText. When I focus this element, a cursor appears and the keyboard shows up. When i know press the back button, the keyboard disappears but the element stays focused and the blinking cursor is still visible.

I tried to manage it with this code i found on other posts, but it doesnt work, I just dont get the event.

```
public boolean dispatchKeyEventPreIme(KeyEvent event) {     
    if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "KeyEvent abgefangen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        search.clearFocus();
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(search.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
    return true;        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried calling `requestFocus()` in another element?

Like for example if you have another TextEdit or something like that

Comment: That works. As I said the problem is, that i cant get the event.

Comment: I don't understand what you wanna do. Can you explain a little more?